# <select> dropdown in IE 9 & 10 triggers 'mouseleave' on <html> node

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I'm listening to 'mouseleave' events on the `<html>` element to trigger a popup when the user tries to close the tab (I'm using a library called [ouibounce](https://github.com/carlsednaoui/ouibounce) for this purpose, not that it really matters). The problem is, `<select>` dropdowns trigger this event when you expand them to see its `<option>`s. T

To my surprise, it seems like this is what IE 9 and 10 do. I cannot reproduce the same behavior in older versions. I stripped everything down to this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $('html').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
          console.log(e);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select>
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
      <option>Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

And as I suspected:

[image]

I tried to capture the event so I can stop propagation, but that didn't work because this is a pure `mouseleave` on `<html>`.

Anyone out there who have dealt with this before? Any help is appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more approriate to listen for `beforeunload` event or something similar ?

Comment: Thanks @adeneo. Perhaps you're right, but I didn't want to go that road since it's an edge case (IE 9 & 10, couldn't reproduce it in IE 11) . Besides, ouibounce is doing its job as expected.

Comment: Thanks @user4749485. Will definitively take a look at that, it looks promising.